# Can I use Turbogears to develop mobile sites?

Tags: python, mobile-website, turbogears

Is it possible to develop mobile versions of webpages using Turbogears? Can someone please show me an example and how it is done?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [tgext.mobilemiddleware](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/tgext.mobilemiddleware) it makes available an **@expose_mobile** decorator that permits to expose a different template engine for mobile devices. It also provides a **tg.request.is_mobile** attribute that can be used inside controllers to apply different execution paths when a mobile device is involved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  TurboGears is just the server side technology, you can generate any type of presentation (HTML) from TurboGears. I recommend taking a look at some articles about developing mobile-friendly websites and/or [this](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=72462).

I don't think there is any example that anyone can show you of a mobile friendly TurboGears application, it will still look the same as any other TurboGears application.  The final result will just have some different HTML output.

There is no magic bullet that will just make an existing website work for all mobile devices (that I know of).  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the Turbogears mailing list (or, [the group on Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/turbogears/)), where you can get more specific answers from people who use Turbogears regularly.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest version of a "mobile site" is simply CSS.  Display a simplified version of the site to USERAGENTS that are identified as mobile.